# Getting error at time of testnet deployment

Tags: smartpy

I was familiarising with smartpy IDE by executing the code as mentioned in the below link

https://tezos.b9lab.com/smartpy/exercise-2

However, when I proceeded to deploy the contract, I am getting the below error and no error when running with test cases.

failed(permanent: proto.009-PsFLoren.michelson_v1.ill_typed_data), (permanent: proto.009-PsFLoren.michelson_v1.invalid_constant), (permanent: proto.009-PsFLoren.michelson_v1.invalid_constant), (permanent: proto.009-PsFLoren.michelson_v1.invalid_constant), (permanent: proto.009-PsFLoren.contract.invalid_contract_notation)

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that error is the invalid address you are using for originating the contract. Below is an example of how to update the initial storage from the origination page.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.. yes, your soution fixed the issue.